# Alternative to Bi Publisher

Tags: reporting

Currently we use [Bi Publisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_BI_Publisher) a fair amount in conjunction with an Oracle DB.

We all find it very finicky to use. It's not as flexible as other web based charting tools like Highcharts and hard to edit layouts without getting a host of errors, things like editing a cron job, when you press edit it doesn't retain the current jobs info, our cron jobs go to email accounts, when we need to add another email account we have to re-add all the email accounts. It's lots of things like that that really wear you down when using it.

Are there any good alternatives to it? Highcharts is very good for charting, but in terms of creating word/PDF docs we've not really experimented with that aspect. Because we find Bi Publisher unproductive we end up exporting stuff from Oracle and replicating in a MySQL + PHP stack to generate the charts.